# Re Export Statement Difference (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

Difference between `export {sayHi} from ‘./say.js’` and `export {default as sayHi} from ‘./say.js’`?

Doesn't the first statement rename default to `sayHi` just like the second one?

Also are these statements valid? If not why?

- `export foo as default from ‘bar.js’`
- `export foo as newFooName from ‘bar.js’`

Comment: Do you have access to a editor and a way to run javascript? It should allow you to answer at least some of these.

Comment: @Evert I tried running both versions for the first question I posed above and I don't think theyre equivalent because my app broke, but I don't know what `export {sayHi} from './say.js` does. The syntax seems a little misleading to me and I have been struggling to find answers

Comment: `export {sayHi} from ...` is similar to `import {sayHi}`. The file that you're importing from must have a named export (not default) with the explicit `sayHi` name like `export function sayHi()`. The `export {sayHi} from ...` imports `sayHi` by name and re-exports it with the same name. So no, they are not equivalent.

Comment: @Evert this confuses me because I thought, `export { } from ...` with braces means that we are importing something that was a default export https://imgur.com/a/F2dRPVm

Comment: No it's explicitly not that. With braces you need the `default` keyword to get the default thing.

Comment: @Evert thank you, just to check my understanding, `export test from ...` == `export {default as test} from ...`

Comment: Yes but that's not what you wrote in your original question. In your question the first two samples both have braces.

Comment: @Evert yeah I know, I mixed things up again and when I tried the example I just posted 2 comments up my app broke, but that was due to something else. anyways for future reference, without braces means we are automatically exporting default, with braces means we are automatically exporting a named export, but still possible to get default with the keyword

Comment: Yes, correct =)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps. There are many ways to export/import in JS, maybe this answer is too teorical but this is my reference to understand how modules works in JS.

```js
//MODULES

module.exports  //exports the module for use in another program.
require()       //imports the module for use in the current program.


//exports / require
//exports   (in menu.js file).
let Menu = {};      //Create an object to represent the module.
Menu.specialty = "Roasted Beet Burger with Mint Sauce";     //Add properties or methods to the module object.
module.exports = Menu;  //Export the module with module.exports.
//require   (in order.js file).
const Menu = require('./menu.js');  //Import the module with require() and assign it to a local variable (the .js extension is optional).
console.log('My order is: ' + Menu.specialty);  // Use the module and its properties within a program.


//export default
let Menu = {};
export default Menu;   //Uses the JavaScript export statement to export JavaScript objects, functions, and primitive data types.
//import
import Menu from './menu';


//Named exports
let burger = 'test';
export { burger };  //Named exports allow us to export data through the use of variables.
//Named imports
import { burger } from './menu';


//Export named exports
export let fries = "fries"; //They can be exported as soon as they are declared
//Import named imports
import { fries } from 'menu';


//Export assign                 
let specialty = "specialty";
export { specialty as chefsSpecial };   // The 'as' keyword allows us to give a variable name.
//Import as
import { chefsSpecial as specialForYou } from 'Menu';


//Another way of using aliases is to import the entire module as an alias:
import * as Carte from './menu';
Carte.chefsSpecial;
Carte.isVeg();
Carte.isLowSodium();
```

Comment: dont think it quite answers my question, but appreciate it nonetheless +1